# find out what font the browser is using and adapt css?

Tags: css, macos, browser

A customer complains that on his mac the css on his website looks terrible. i checked it and found out that he uses some settings in his browser to set the font to a specific one and also have a minimum height.

The problem now is that some of the css depends on heights and now is not working right.
is there any chance i can detect such things and override the css? (besides doing it with php and load a custom css)

Comment: If telling the client that "nobody else will have the problem so it's not a real problem" isn't an option, you should fix this by changing your CSS so that *stuff* no longer requires an exact height. Detecting whether or not the user has set custom font settings and then if so loading new CSS is the wrong approach.

Comment: User agent has ultimate say in font styling if they want it (most let the site set it), so you cannot override a user's settings if they have it set so that you can't. The best thing to do is have a flexible enough design to allow for font variation (setting hieghts by `em` units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments above. If a user customizes their local font settings the onus should not be on you to make it work. They've overwritten your intended design. That being said, here's a way to detect fonts using JavaScript.

http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/

Comment: haha the method is quite impressive, but not useable for a productive website... okay then i will try to set the height so that it works...